# Can't access BIOS for USB install

Tags: system-installation, usb, uefi, bios

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my second machine now from a USB startup disk. The disk works fine as I used it yesterday to install on another machine.

The problem is on this second IBM machine: when I go to BOOT menu (by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>) I do not see `boot from USB`. The only other option that might be similar is `REMOVABLE DEVICE`. When I select this option and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> nothing happens. The light on the USB stick doesn't even flash, just my old Windows boots up normally.

I have been attempting to access the BIOS, but the only thing I can seem to get access to is the *IBM Setup Utility* which seems like the BIOS, but isn't that blue screen like on my other machine. Can anyone please help me figure out how to get this going so I can install Ubuntu again?

Answer (score 1):

ploplinux is a bootable iso that will allow a machine to boot from USB or CDROM if it is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Install PLoP using EasyBCD on Windows

CLICK [Here](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-boot-from-usb-drive-even-if-your-pc-doesnt-support-booting-from-usb/)

[Download](https://neosmart.net/Download/Register/1) EasyBCD **[Just type any name or email-id and click "Download!"]**

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

i don't have much experience with ibm brand machines,   are you able to find anything that represents a boot device order?  on one of my pc's the usb stick appears in the list of connected hard drives and i have to move it to the top of the list for my computer to attempt to boot from it.

Comment: if i press f12 it asks for boot device, but nothing about the order

Comment: have you tried pressing the f2, f10 or delete keys while you pc is going through the post process?

Comment: yes I have tried all those keys with no luck

Comment: do you know exactly what the model of the system your using is?

Comment: on the motherboard it says IBN:REV: 2.7

Comment: thats just the revision of the mother board production

Comment: ok... trying to do this from memory...  push right across to boot.. and the options you need shouldbe in there

Comment: if your bios looks like hte first picture you linked...

use the right arrow on the keyboard to move across to the [boot] tab.

in there should be the option to set your boot device priority.

Comment: ok so i found the Startup Sequence in teh IBM setup utility, and made the first boot object REMOVABLE MEDIA. there is no USB option. In any casem It wontboot from USB, only HD

Comment: you said you have the cd as well.. that should boot with those options

Comment: I have tired booting with the CD. It will boot form teh WINDOWS CD, but not the UBUNTU one!

Comment: OK well if it boots from your windows CD and not the Ubuntu CD then you have burnt the ubuntu cd as non bootable. Try burning it again

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the same for you, but my IBM Thinkpad registers my live USB on the boot menu as a USB hard disk.

Comment: I even jsut updated my BIOS hoping there would be some USB support, but the only thing that even looks remotely close is 'removable devices' . Still no luck. I know the USB drive is setup proper as well, because when i put it in on my other machine that allows USB boot it loads fine..

Comment: Based on what I've seen so far, some BIOSes don't boot automatically from USB despite the boot order.

Comment: my machine will boot from the Windows CD fine, but will not boot from the UBUNTU install disk. The files on the CD are exactly the same ones copied form the USB stick that works as install on my other machine. Both systems are 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

If the BIOS/UEFI setup utility on your computer is not accessible, then it is possible that your computer's firmware is preconfigured to boot from bootable USB drives automatically, and the problem is that the bootable USB drive has not been created correctly, not that the BIOS/UEFI setup utility is not accessible.

Did you create your Ubuntu installation media correctly? There are instructions for creating a bootable Ubuntu live USB at: [What is the proper way of creating installation media from an Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso).

Comment: unfortunately my bios looks like this:

[link]http://ice.he.net/~hedden/images/boot_seq_Phoenix.jpg

Answer (score -1):

ANSWER: CD was not bootable. WHen burned form windows the disk was not being read as an image. In windows the ISO file is read as a winrar archive which was not readable. I simply burned the CD on my other UBUNTU machine as DISK IMAGE and set the BOOT sequence to boot from CD, and it worked.

Comment: What? Have You any Sense? Are you kidding here?
You told that light on USB does not even flash!
USB? or DVD? Crap Question and its own crap answer.

Comment: Can't access BIOS for **USB install**?